# Error: Parameter 2 (request) is required. [schemaUtils:39]

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use the Google Chrome Extention [JavaScript Errors Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-errors-notifie/jafmfknfnkoekkdocjiaipcnmkklaajd/details). Now i get on EVERY Site (also on SO) the Error: ***Error: Parameter 2 (request) is required. [schemaUtils:39]***. 
Is this my fault or is this a bug in the extention which must be [reportet](http://code.google.com/p/javascript-error-notifier/issues/list)? 
Found nothing in google or on their website...

Comment: The extension works for me without this error. Maybe another extension which interferes with it?

Comment: Hm. Ok thanks for reply. I activate all other extentions step by step...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Extention was disturbed by another extention named [Magic Inputs Filler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/magic-inputs-filler/dgchjemniofpmdkgnoejdkgomjldfgmh).

Comment: This error is caused by a variety of extensions, not only Magic Input Filler, especially those who manipulate JavaScript or HTML. So if you develop make sure, that you deactivate you extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I deactivated the breakpoints and then reactivated them. Error was gone. Like here 
http://prntscr.com/4ixknk