# Error in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have recently started to see a frequent error in Chrome Dev Tools when right clicking on an element for the purposes of selecting "Inspect Element" - instead of selecting the element on the "*Elements" tab the error "Uncaught Error: Parameter 2 (message) is required.*" appears in the "Sources" tab for a virtual "extensions:: schemaUtils" script.

The error occurs in the function "validate" as per the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of error in DevTools]

This error seems to occur since installing the "OneTab" extension, and indeed goes away when I disable it. I have reported it to the extension author, so far without response. Unfortunately as work have seen fit to issue me with an underpowered machine, removing OneTab is not an option as memory otherwise runs in extremely short supply.

The issue is easy to replicate, within Stack Overflow itself click on the "StackExchange" icon top left, and then right click on one of the "Your Communities" items. The context menu does not open and the above error appears. This also affects the pop-out menus on the primary product I am working on.

This error only occurs in a single instance of Chrome, which happens to be my primary developer machine, and does **not** occur on Chrome Canary on the same computer, and with the same extension installed.

Chrome 37.0.2024.2m on a Windows 7 Professional, Service Pack 1, x64 laptop.

Do I have a corrupted copy of Chrome? Can other users replicate this error (with or without the OneTab extension)? Is there anything short of removing the extension permanently that I can do to restore essential "Inspect Element" functionality?

I have already tried resetting Chrome within the settings menu.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain what I have done wrong so I can improve future questions? StackOverflow explicitly covers "software tools commonly used by programmers" and I do not believe this to be a bug within the extension as it works within other instances of the Chrome browser.

Comment: I don't know what it is, but I have it too, and it irritates the hell out of me.  It DOES occur on my Canary build.  It does not appear to be related to any flag;extension; or setting.

Comment: Just a follow up.  I've confirmed that it is caused.by the "OneTab" extension.  After disabling, it disappeared.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193129/error-parameter-2-request-is-required-schemautils39 (and my answer below)

Answer (score 9):

The problem you're experiencing is that a breakpoint is triggered for (uncaught) errors.

To stop this from happening, open the Sources tab of the developer tools, and make sure that the circle with the two stripes in it is GREY, not blue. This circle means "Pause on exception" and is the right-most icon in the next picture.

[image]

Comment: The error is still appearing in the console as it is still being thrown, but this at least allows me to Inspect Elements - so a good workaround for now. It does make it a bit harder to debug errors in our own code as we can't inspect the objects at the time of the error without going back and adding console.log or breakpoints, but I'll take that pain over losing the ability to inspect elements. Thanks.

Comment: It happens for me too. That icon is gray and it occures again when i right click on elements.

Answer (score 5):

Just stating more clearly : if you are ok with that, just disable the OneTab Chrome extension.

Comment: "removing OneTab is not an option as memory otherwise runs in extremely short supply" - this isn't really an answer

Comment: You are correct. I don't mean "for you, it's the answer". I mean, "for most people googling the error and landing on this page, it is probably the answer". Maybe I'll create a new question to post this answer...

Comment: done : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237260/chrome-console-uncaught-error-parameter-2-is-required-in-extensions-schema/28237284#28237284

Answer (score 0):

de-activating and re-activating breakpoints in the devtools solved my issue

The breakpoints icon is in Developer Tools, on the Sources tab, the icon left of the pause button.

I also use OneTab, am on OSX 10.10.5, Google Chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit) - other extensions I have installed are LastPass, Xdebug helper, JetBrains, Postman, DevTools Theme: Zero Dark Matrix, Google Docs (and similar)

The breakpoints solution was suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25623760/1875965

Answer (score 0):

You started the validation at `i + 1`, it should be `i`.
Change:

```
var message = "Invalid Argument for " + (i + 1) + ".";
```

Into:

```
var message = "Invalid Argument for " + (i) + ".";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Heather. To be clear, this is code from the OneTab extension and dating from 2014. I did not write it, and I imagine by now it has been changed.